# Galaxy S3 : Impossible to go to recovery or download mode

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-3, boot

I've just get an old Galaxy S3, with this mission to backup existing photos on it.
Of course, it's not rooted and not backuped... :) Original setup (ROM, ...)

When starting it it's stucked on Galaxy S3 logo screen without any change.

When trying to go to download mode : It's keep restarting after 2-3s
Same for recovery mode.

Each time I removed battery. I've tested with the phone plugged in or not. Plugged to the computer or not, etc...

Any idea? :)

Thanks
Philippe

Comment: charge or replace battery

Comment: The S3 has a known bug in it's EMMC firmware that can cause the [sudden death syndrome](https://media.ccc.de/v/34c3-8784-emmc_hacking_or_how_i_fixed_long-dead_galaxy_s3_phones). May be the device you have is affected?